# How do I pass output from cache to a REST source request body

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

In a data flow, given a dataset with a REST source using POST method, I want to to use a dynamic expression for the request body. I've created 2 sources - source1 sinks a simple CSV list to Cache  sink1(with no key columns), source2 references the cached output.

[data flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/grYff.png)

Source2 has the request body expression: `sink1#output().name`. This all validates.

When I try preview source2 I get this error mentioning **Unresolved specification**.

```
Spark job failed: {
"text/plain": "{\"runId\":\"3cf3b288-4986-4c78-8026-2d2f6eef3879\",\"sessionId\":\"71c10e74-22d3-45a9-945f-ff65c3ed34ae\",\"status\":\"Failed\",\"payload\":{\"statusCode\":400,\"shortMessage\":\"DF-DRAFT_001 at Source 'source2'(Line 17/Col 0): Unresolved specification\",\"detailedMessage\":\"Failure 2023-08-31 13:09:54.283 failed DebugManager.processJob, run=3cf3b288-4986-4c78-8026-2d2f6eef3879, errorMessage=DF-DRAFT_001 at Source 'source2'(Line 17/Col 0): Unresolved specification\"}}\n"
}
```

I'm expecting this to take the first row of sink1 cache and give me the "name" string column value and use that as the request body. The request does work if I just use a different expression e.g. a data flow parameter value.

Comment: Can you provide your dataflow JSON for better understanding?

Comment: See dataflow JSON: https://gist.github.com/lroos/a3c37c968d66eec5e541ac66b3f24de8

Answer (score 0):

I really dont know why, but this worked for me:

```
@activity('Data flow1').output.runStatus.output.sink1.value[0]
```

Note: You may have to change 'sink1' for however is called your cache sink, as well as your data flow name.

Comment: This is correct to read the activity output from the pipeline, but I’m trying to use a cache lookup from within the same data flow.